# Get a numerical cell value in a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-loc

```
import pandas as pd

Sem_limiar = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\Luiz Alegro\\Downloads\\BR1_Trend_IBOV_portfolio_holding_and_NAVs_10.csv", skiprows=5, skipfooter=16, names=['Date', 'NAV', 'Return', 'Interest', 'NAVvlty', 'FiltRet', 'NAV_SEM'], engine='python')
Com_limiar = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\Luiz Alegro\\Downloads\\BR1_Trend_IBOV2_portfolio_holding_and_NAVs_10.csv", skiprows=5, skipfooter=16, names=['Date', 'NAV', 'Return', 'Interest', 'NAVvlty', 'FiltRet_', 'NAV_COM'], engine='python')

Sem_limiar = Sem_limiar[['Date','NAV_SEM']]
Com_limiar = Com_limiar[['Date','NAV_COM']]

Sem_limiar['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(Sem_limiar['Date'])
Com_limiar['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(Com_limiar['Date'])

Resumo5 = Sem_limiar
Resumo5['NAV_COM'] = Com_limiar['NAV_COM']

Resumo5.set_index('Date', drop=True, inplace=True)

display(Resumo5.loc['2012-01-04','NAV_SEM'])
```

> I can´t get the float value a specific cell in the pandas dataframe. What should I use? .loc?

Comment: `iloc[i]` will give you the `ith` row. Is this what yo are looking for?

Comment: can you provide a [mcve] of your data as well as what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I have tried iloc[i] but the index is a date. It didn´t work. I got the right result using float(pd.loc[ ][ ]). Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be this simple:

```
float(df['column_name'][row_number])
```

where:

- `df` is the dataframe
- `column_name` is the name of the column
- `row_number` is an integer number for the row.

the function `float()` does the conversion to a float.

Example dataframe:

```
   year  average_temperature
0  1820              -6.1100
1  1821              -5.5600
2  1822              -5.8500
3  1823              -6.3550
4  1824              -5.1754
5  1825              -5.1500
```

The float of the row 3 average temperature:

```
float(df['average_temperature'][3])
```